# Regex: find a space between two words

Tags: regex

I have this string:

> Miami 25 JOHN H. DOE  3059715648 Coral Gables

I want to find the following spaces using regular expressions:

Miami   25 **[SPACE]** JOHN H. DOE  3059715648 **[SPACE]** Coral Gables

I want to ignore all other spaces like between John H. Doe

Thank you!

Comment: find a space, then what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Clarify your logic of finding these spaces?

Comment: You need a way to logically distinguish the spaces you want from the spaces you don't want. For example, will the rule, *Only find spaces that come after numbers* work for you? It works for the single example you show, but it's unclear from your question whether that's adequate for all your strings you want to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use lookarounds to do this in the given string, not sure the logic behind this though.

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=\D)
```

This asserts that at the current position in the string, what precedes is a digit and what follows is any character thats not a digit, if successful **space** character(s) are matched.

Comment: +1 - to be donated to the Great Crystal Ball of Figuring Out What The User Actually Wanted. It should perhaps be pointed out that in non-Javascript regex, \d will also match things like "١" (aka ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE).

Comment: Why the Great Crystal Ball? =)

Comment: @hwnd Any other charity will do. It was just a +1 for seeing what the OP wanted when they hadn't explicitly stated it (and providing a good answer which I too may find useful).

Comment: Here is my solution [^0-9A-Z,\n]

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Z])
```

This would match one or more spaces after a digit and it must be followed by an Uppercase letter.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/4)

Comment: Great! this regex works too! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?(\\d+)(\\s+)(.*))
```

Java Code Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?(\\d+)(\\s+)(.*))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Miami 25 JOHN H. DOE 3059715648 Coral Gables");
if(m.matches()) {
    //m.group(2) = 25
    //m.group(4) = JOHN H. DOE 3059715648 Coral Gables
}
```